# How do i achieve this nested layout in meteor?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am trying to build an application using MeteorJS. My main layout has a topnav and a yield.

```
-------------------------------------
|               TopNav              |
-------------------------------------
|                                   |
|                                   |
|              Yield                |
|                                   |                                                
|                                   |
|                                   |
-------------------------------------
```

However on certain pages in the application, the template inside yield needs to have a sidebar and another place for nesting sub-templates.

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| item1                   |                              |                               
| item2                   |                              |                                    
| item3                   |                              |                                                       
| item4                   |                              |
| item5                   |          Corresponding       |
|                         |            Templates         |
|                         |                              |                         
|                         |                              |
|                         |                              |                       
|                         |                              |
|                         |                              |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

How do i achieve this. I am using iron-router.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a wrapper template to hold the other two, and use CSS to position them correctly...

```
<template name="left"> ... </template>
<template name="right"> ... </template>
<template name="wrapper"> 
   {{>left}}
   {{>right}}
</template>
```

and then load template wrapper into your yield.